# Django custom form - cleaned_data has incorrect values for IntegerField

Tags: python, django

In my Django app (v. 3.1), I've added a custom form to trigger a data export that, among other things, can collect two integer values that represent years in a date range. When the form is submitted, no matter what values the user has set in the number fields, the values that appear in the form's `cleaned_data` attribute are the values that were set as `initial` for those fields on the definition of the form class.

For example, the initial value of the field should be `2022` - but no matter what value the user sets in the input, the value in `form.cleaned_data` for the field is `2022`.

A `ChoiceField` in the form works as expected, and I'm pretty inexperienced with Django - so I can't quite figure out what I've done wrong here. Here's a slightly simplified version of the code...

`observation/forms.py`:

```
from django import forms
import datetime

export_formats = [
    'csv',
    'xls',
    'xlsx',
]
export_format_choices = [(f, f) for f in export_formats]
min_year = 1950

class ExportForm(forms.Form):
    current_year = datetime.datetime.now().year

    export_format = forms.ChoiceField(required=True, label='Format', choices=export_format_choices)
    year_from = forms.IntegerField(required=False, disabled=True, min_value=min_year, max_value=current_year, initial=current_year)
    year_through = forms.IntegerField(required=False, disabled=True, min_value=min_year, max_value=current_year, initial=current_year)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ExportForm, self).__init__(*args)
```

`admin.py`

```
def export_view(self, request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ExportForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            export_format = form.cleaned_data['export_format']
            data_scope = 'all'
            year_range = ''

            year_range = f'_{form.cleaned_data["year_from"]}-{form.cleaned_data["year_through"]}'
            query_params &= Q(created_at__year__gte=form.cleaned_data['year_from'])
            query_params &= Q(created_at__year__lte=form.cleaned_data['year_through'])

            query = Observation.objects.filter(query_params).select_related('items')
            dataset = ObservationResource().export(query)
            response = HttpResponse(getattr(dataset, export_format), content_type=export_format)
            response['Content-Disposition'] = f'attachment; filename="items_data_{data_scope}{year_range}.{export_format}"'

            return response

    return TemplateResponse(request, 'export.html')
```

So the line `form.cleaned_data['export_format']` in `admin.py` is set to the correct value - and if I examine `form.POST`, I can see the correct values for `year_from` and `year_through` being set (in this case, 2019 and 2020) -

```
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['...'], 'year_from': ['2019'], 'year_through': ['2020'], 'export_format': ['csv']}>
```

but the `cleaned_data` appears as

```
{'export_format': 'csv', 'year_from': 2022, 'year_through': 2022}
```

Why is it that the `cleaned_data` for these `IntegerField`s does not reflect the data in `form.POST`? Thanks much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your form definition you have

```
year_from = forms.IntegerField(required=False, disabled=True,
```

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/fields/#disabled)

> The disabled boolean argument, when set to True, disables a form field
> using the disabled HTML attribute so that it won’t be editable by
> users. Even if a user tampers with the field’s value submitted to the
> server, it will be ignored in favor of the value from the form’s
> initial data.

If you want users to be able to edit the value, removing this attribute should do the trick.

Comment: Thaaank you, that makes perfect sense. In practice, what I was doing here was disabling those fields by default, but a user could opt to toggle them on in the UI... this is actually a really great feature, but I wasn't aware of it. Much appreciated.